# CMake cannot find lboost_* in mingw

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake

​Installed:

- Windows 10 64 bit
- cmake version 3.21.3
- gcc (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.3.0 (MinGW 4.8.X and The latest version)

While executing the make command on the CMakeLists.txt file, I encountered the error can not find lboost _filesystem, followed by the link https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_77_0.html, boost for  my system I created, however this does not work for me.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(obj_loader)

execute_process(COMMAND python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.sysconfig.get_include())" OUTPUT_VARIABLE Tensorflow_default_INCLUDE_DIRS)
set(Tensorflow_INCLUDE_DIRS "${Tensorflow_default_INCLUDE_DIRS}" CACHE PATH "Tensorflow include path")
include_directories(${Tensorflow_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES obj_loader.cpp)
add_library(obj_loader SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(obj_loader boost_filesystem)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPsIw.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message to be in the **question post**, not linked as *image*. As for the linking with `boost_filesystem` library, you need to help CMake to find it. E.g. you could specify absolute path to that library (which depends on how do you install Boost). Or you could try to use `find_package(Boost)` for  locate Boost libraries. There are many information in the net (and on the Stack Overvlow particularly) about using Boost in CMake.

Comment: Thank you for your welcome! I am currently using cmake version 3.21.3 and find _package is for version 3.12 and lower! But the main problem is that I tested Boost 1.55, 1.74 and 1.77 and none of them work for me! Even in cmake -gni the boost is not detected. I have created the necessary paths in the enviroment variable, which I describe below:
in system variable:
1. BOOST_ROOT: C: \ local \ boost_1_74_0
2. BOOST_INCLUDEDIR: C: \ local \ boost_1_74_0
3. BOOST_LIBRARYDIR: C: \ local \ boost_1_74_0 \ lib64-msvc-14.2

Comment: In target_link_libraries (obj_loader boost_filesystem) In CMakeLists.txt (first post) the programmer uses the boost_filesystem system and I do not know what he means !? Is there a hypothesis that the programmer does not mean boost_filesystem files? Or should the code run on a Linux operating system, for example?

Comment: Finally I want to compile a file written in C ++ to read .obj and use it in Python but I could not :(

Here is a list of all the tools that are installed on the system:
- Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 
- python 3.7 and 3.9
- Visual Studio Code x64 1.60.0
- MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit
- Cmake version 3.21.3
- tensorflow 1.13.1 And other things like cuda 10 , cudnn 10

Thank you in advance
Any idea is welcome