# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Eigen/Core': No such file or directory / explicit specialization; 'std :: hash 'has already been defined

Tags: tensorflow, visual-c++, cmake

I have a **CMakeList.txt** file that I want to run!
I tried two solutions, both of which failed. I posted the first way at [CMake cannot find lboost_* in mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69396777/cmake-cannot-find-lboost-in-mingw) and gave a full description of it.
Second way: When compiling the same file with Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 Release - amd64, I got the following error:
C: \ ... \ third_party \ eigen3 \ unsupported \ Eigen \ CXX11 \ ../../../ Eigen / Core (1): fatal error C1083: **Cannot open include file: 'eigen3 / Eigen / Core': No such file or directory**
So I changed Core file from  **#include <eigen / core>** to **#include <eigen3 / Eigen / Core>** but the problem was not resolved. Finally I added eigen3 manually to the path and the error type changed and now I get the following errors:
[build] C: \ ... \ tensorflow / core / framework / **numeric_types.h (121): error C2766: explicit specialization; 'std :: hash ' has already been defined**
[build] C: \ Program Files \ Python37 \ Lib \ site-packages \ tensorflow \ include \ Eigen \ src / Core / arch / Default / **Half.h (934): note: see previous definition of 'hash**  '
[build] C: \ Program Files \ Python37 \ Lib \ site-packages \ tensorflow \ include \ unsupported \ Eigen \ CXX11 \ src / Tensor / TensorMap.h (43): **note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen :: Tensor <T, 1,1, int> 'being compiled**

I am very tired and confused and do not know how to solve this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: So this question post has the error message, but doesn't have a code. And [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69396777/cmake-cannot-find-lboost-in-mingw) has the code but doesn't have an error message (links and images are not counted). This is not how Stack Overflow works: we expected **every question post** to be **self-contained**, with the code and the error message included.

Comment: And please, format the error message in the same way as a code. In the referenced question the code is formatted with triple-backtick at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.